# Manually set authentication with ReactiveSecurityContextHolder

Tags: spring-security, reactive-programming

I'm trying to setup Spring Security with Spring Web Flux. I don't understand how to manually set the `SecurityContext` with `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`. Do you have any resource or hint?
Take for example this filter I've written that reads a JWT token and needs to set the authentication manually:

```
@Slf4j
public class JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter implements WebFilter {

    private final JwtAuthenticationConfig config;

    private final JwtParser jwtParser = Jwts.parser();

    public JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(JwtAuthenticationConfig config) {
        this.config = config;
        jwtParser.setSigningKey(config.getSecret().getBytes());
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

        String token = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(config.getHeader());
        if (token != null && token.startsWith(config.getPrefix() + " ")) {
            token = token.replace(config.getPrefix() + " ", "");
            try {
                Claims claims = jwtParser.parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
                String username = claims.getSubject();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<String> authorities = claims.get("authorities", List.class);
                if (username != null) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null,
                            authorities.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList()));

                    // TODO set authentication into ReactiveSecurityContextHolder 
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.warn(ex.toString(), ex);
                ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            }
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I managed to update the SecurityContext by calling:

```
return chain.filter(exchange).subscriberContext(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(auth));
```

Correct me if I'm wrong or if there is a better way to manage it.

Comment: hi! Can you share the complete code excerpt? Thanks :)

Comment: That's posted in the question!

Comment: @AlessandroDionisi How did you figure this out? Is there any good source, besides wondering through the code?

Comment: `subscriberContext` is deprecated in Springboot 3.0

Answer (score 3):

I searched a lot about this issue and get this thing worked.
You can try setting the context while passing the filter chain like below.

```
return chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication));
```

Comment: What if you are getting your Authentication object in a reactive way?
Like in a Mono<Authentication>