# Trouble getting SecurityContext from ReactiveSecurityContextHolder in a WebFilter

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, spring-security, spring-webflux

In my Webflux application, I'm trying to use JWT tokens for stateless sessions with Spring Security. I have two WebFilters, one that generates the token, and one that validates it. My token generation filter works fine, but my validation filter is acting up. Its filter method looks as follows:

```
@Override
protected Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    final String jwt = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(authHeader);
    
    try {
        SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(signingKey);
        
        Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(key)
                .build().parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
        
        var authorities = Toolkit.getAuthorities(String.valueOf(claims.get("authorities")));
        String user = String.valueOf(claims.get("username"));
        
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().flatMap((context) -> {
            context.setAuthentication(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            user, null, authorities));
            
            return chain.filter(exchange);
        });
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
        
        e.printStackTrace();
        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }
}
```

Everything inside of ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().flatMap() never gets called, which as a result breaks the filter chain since chain.filter() is called inside flatMap(). Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: you do know that spring security already has full support for jwts? read the docs

Comment: @Toerktumlare well isn't that lovely, now do you have an actual answer as to why this isn't working?

Comment: After reading the above comment, not anymore, good luck with your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498838/manually-set-authentication-with-reactivesecuritycontextholder

Comment: @Toerktumlare won't need it my guy

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing

```
return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext().flatMap((context) -> {
        context.setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user, null, authorities));
        
        return chain.filter(exchange);
});
```

to

```
Context context = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                user, null, authorities));
        
return chain.filter(exchange).contextWrite(context);
```

From what I'm seeing the former didn't work because it doesn't have an Authentication object associated.